# How to redirect always to the same page in a Flask app

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am running a Flask application and I want to implement a functionality that keeps a user in the same page until some process is completed, but if he leaves and come back the user will see the same page, also if he tries to return the page, he will be redirected to the same page.
He will be able to make another action when the process is completed.
Some idea?
Thanks in advance for the help.

I tried to disable the mouse clicks, also to make something like login redirecting, but I can't get it yet, because it is very tricky.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by, "but if he leaves and comes back the user will see the same page." Could you give us an example of your case?

Comment: Suppose that my page has several directions, for example, www.mysite.com/subpage1, www.mysite.com/subpage2, www.mysite.com/subpage3, etc. I would like that if a user is in subpage2 and he leaves, when he come back, he will see the subpage2 unless the process described above is completed.

Answer (score 0):

it is not flask issue, it is web app mechanism, you cannot stop user do everything in browser.

you can use session or db to store user state, and redirect / block requests what you want to

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try setting up a user status first.